# Android Authorized.net integration put API LOGIN ID, TRANSACTION KEY, SECRET KEY

Tags: android, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I have implemented authorization.net integration using [this](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-android) android and I have testing using sandbox account and it is working fine, once I have done transaction sucessfully, I also got confirmation email but If user make payment then how can I notifies that I have received payment like `paypal`. and where `transaction key` can I put. Please know me as I am not more awaire of it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will your application reside on the customer or the merchant's device?

Comment: @ rhldr, Thanks for reply actually my application is for merchant's device. Here is my complete code. [Here is my complete code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0OXBbfffzFRdDVKQ1VvNnQ4U28)  I am not sure where I have to put necessary information so that once custome make payment through        authorized.net so we can received notification.

Comment: Instead of API Login and Transaction Key, the merchant should use a Login ID and Password for authentication.  You should not store sensitive information on the mobile device.

Comment: @rhldr I am trying to integrate Authorize.Net android use only for customer so I want to ask only Card number , expried date etc.. information for customer not the Login id and password screen. I run the sample app using this https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-android. Do you implement the sample code for customer or please provide guidance.

Comment: @SakibSyed you give the access sample that you developed but that app is for merchant' device. Do you implement the sample code for customer use where app will ask directly card number . security code etc....